# What is the method to pass a variable to body field in Uipath while using httprequest (json format)?

Tags: json, post, webhooks, slack, uipath

So, this is what I am working on UiPath..I have slack webhook.. I am POSTing using that webhook.. I have a variable "body" which is of type string.. I want to send that to slack using webhook..
In the body field, I used

```
"{""text"":"""+body+"""}"
```

And I checked the status code, it was 400..
And BodyFormat is 'application/json'
I sent a normal text without any concatenation, it worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

the body looks okay to me in how you have it.

You mentioned using POST method, but I'd double check that utilising the "PUT" method

Also check that your Accept Format is set to JSON rather than Any.

No need to change your BodyFormat as "application/json" is correct